# RSpec Stubbing: return in a sequence

Tags: ruby, rspec, stub

I know the following things work:

returning a parameter

```
subject.should_receive(:get_user_choice){ |choices| choices.to_a[0] }
```

and a sequence (it will return a 0 on the first call, and the second time "exit")

```
subject.should_receive(:get_user_choice).and_return(0, "exit")
```

But how to combine them?
what if I would like to return the parameter the first time and then return "exit"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively:

```
subject.should_receive(:get_user_choice).ordered.and_return { |choices| choices.to_a[0] }
subject.should_receive(:get_user_choice).ordered.and_return { "exit" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not most elegant, but how about:

```
n = 0
subject.should_receive(:get_user_choice){|choices|
   (n += 1) < 2 ? choices.to_a[0] : "exit"
}
```

Comment: when I tried this in irb, it didn't seem to update the counter... must have done something terribly wrong (probably spelling.. sigh ;-))
Thanks, this is working for me now!